# Set the display name using memory provider in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, testing

I am currently trying to create some tests for an application, but I'm stuck on authentication.

In the app I use ldap authentication, which also determines the role of each user. It works well, but to simplify the testing (and to not use real users) I use the `in_memory` provider in my tests.

The problem is that in my views I use `{{ app.user.displayname }`}, and the display name is not available with the in_memory provider.

Is there a way to add it ? For example this solution (which does not work) would be perfect :

```
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                john:  { password: john, roles: 'ROLE_USER', displayname: 'John Doe' }
                admin:  { password: admin, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN', displayname: 'Admin' }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either modify the class

```
src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/InMemoryUserProvider.php
```

so it uses the displayname as well or (even better) create your own class which will extend the `InMemoryUserProvider` and use your own provider (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html)

Comment: Did you succeed? I need much the same thing